# Capturing connection errors

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

Following on from [my Connections query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32436110/2877364), I now want to capture any connections that cannot be reached and throw an error message to state that the relevant connection cannot be reached.

This is the code I have so far, however, I'm not sure if it's capturing any errors:

```
Private Sub btnRefreshConns_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection

    For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        cn.Refresh
    Next

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "A connection could not be reached" & cn.Name & ": " & cn.Description

End Sub
```

Could someone please assist me or let me know if this code would work?

Comment: As for the ErrorHandler, should I be displaying the err.Description or will my code above display the connection name and description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the sample will catch connection errors.  Change the `MsgBox` line to this to fix the reporting:

```
MsgBox "A connection could not be reached: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
```

`Err` has info about the latest error.

There's only one catch: *all* errors will be caught, not just connection errors.  That is why I suggest not referring to `cn` in your error handler: you don't know what state it will be in if an unrelated error happens (say, out of memory - which can happen!).  A better approach is to wrap just the code of interest.  Inside your For loop:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    cn.Refresh
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Reset default error handling
```

**Edit**: The `On Error GoTo 0` unhooks your `ErrorHandler` and returns to the default error-handling mode, which is to show the error dialog box.  The `0` is just a magic number that VBA is programmed to recognize for this purpose.  See more details and explanation at [Chip Pearson's page on the subject](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm), which is my personal go-to reference.

I have never used `On Error GoTo  -1`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994055/2877364) suggests I'm not missing anything :) .  It is apparently used to continue executing normal code after `ErrorHandler`, but I have always used `Resume` for that and had no problems.

Caveat: never never never forget the `Exit Sub` before `ErrorHandler`.  I did once and got stuck in an infinite error loop I could only escape by killing Excel.  `Resume` causes an error if you run it when an error isn't actually being handled and that error threw to the error handler having the `Resume`... yeah.  Ugly.

Comment: What does the '0' do, as opposed to 'line' or '-1'?

Comment: @sean Edited - check out the revisions

Comment: Thank you for the references.